# Does the term "Proportional" have different meanings?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I have recently been confused by the term "Proportional". This started when I came across 2 different websites that seem to contradict one another when it comes to $y = x^2$. The first implies that the two variables are proportional, but the second appears to deny this.

- [Is Proportional link (mathisfun, near the bottom of webpage)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/directly-inversely-proportional.html)
- [Is NOT Proportional link (khan, near the end of the video)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-seventh-grade-math/cc-7th-ratio-proportion/cc-7th-proportional-rel/v/testing-whether-area-is-proportional-to-side-length)

I am sure that I am missing something and/or being overwhelmed by overloaded terms as both are reputable resources. The forms of proportional relationships that I am familiar with are the directly and indirectly proportional equations of $y = k * x$ and $y = k/x$ with '$k$' being a constant. So when I read that equations of the form $y = x^2$ (presumably w/ '$k$' $= 1$) being considered proportional, it throws me off. Also, the exponential form of $y= a * b^x$, where '$a$' is a constant, now has me rethinking its proportional nature . . . which to me has always just been based on the factor '$b$'. If one can say that "$y$ is proportional to $x^2$", then why can't one say "$y$ is proportional to $x+1$" (i.e. $y = 1 * (x + 1)$? I am clearly confused and would surely appreciate being set straight. Many thanks.

Comment: No, it means 'linearly related to' as in y = ax + b. That's the ONLY meaning.

Comment: You misread; the first link does _not_ suggest that the variables in $y=x^2$ are proportional.  It claims that, in the equation $d=kt^2$, $d$ is proportional to _the square of $t$._ (In $y=x^2$, then, $y$ is proportional _to the square of $x$._)

Comment: @mistermarko dont you mean 'affinely related to'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As columbus8myhw explained in a comment, you misinterpreted the first link. In $y=x^2$, it is not $y$ and $x$ that are proportional, but $y$ and $x^2$. Indeed, as you suggest, $y$ can be proportional to $x+1$, or in fact to any function of $x$.

Comment: Thanks @joriki. I see that I did not characterize the question accurately. However, I remain unclear. For y = x^2, I am under the impression that the ratio between all x^2 and y for this equation will not have the same ratio. So it is strange to be told that the relationship between y and x^2 is proportional. But, based on your last statement, it seems that you are using the term proportional in y=x^2 with an intended interpretation of something like: the value of y can be determined by squaring the value of x. Please advise.

Comment: @AlonzoArcher: No, I mean quite literally that $y$ is proportional to $x^2$. I don't understand what you mean by "the ratio between all $x^2$ and $y$ for this equation will not have the same ratio". If $y=x^2$, then the ratio between $x^2$ and $y$ will always be $1$.

Comment: Ah, @joriki I think I see my confusion ... I am still mixing up the ratio of y/x and y/(x^2). So then, when your given the form y=k*x for defining an equation with a proportional relationship, why can we then disregard the fact that x is not transformed in the definition, and yet we can transform x by squaring it y=(x^2) and calling it a proportional relationship? Can you replace the x in the definition with g(x), so that you could also define a proportional equation with the form y=k*g(x)? And if so, can you substitute a function anywhere you see a variable in Mathematical definitions?

Comment: Hi @joriki, I found the following on Wikipedia: "In more advanced mathematics, a variable is a symbol that denotes a mathematical object, which could be a number, a vector, a matrix, or even a function. In this case, the original property of "variability" of a variable is not kept (except, sometimes, for informal explanations)." So since the general definition for proportional does not seem to define any particular type of objects for 'x', sounds like it can be a function. I think I got it. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi @joriki, my apologies for bothering you with this matter again. But, when I compare your statement above that in  y=x^2, y is proportional to x^2, with the "Difference" section found under this link:       [link] http://www.ehow.com/info_8531541_difference-between-proportional-linear-relationships.html.   The article seems to claim the all proportional equations are liner - I am just not sure what to think. Do you have any clarity to offer?

Comment: I struggled with that last comment, this is a slightly better version:            Hi @joriki, my apologies for bothering you with this matter again. But, when I compare your statement above that in  y=x^2, y is proportional to x^2, with the "Difference" section found under this link:       [link] http://www.ehow.com/info_8531541_difference-between-proportional-linear-relationships.html, I become confused because the article seems to claim the all proportional equations are linear. But, in y=x^2, we have a nonlinear relationship. Do you have any clarity to offer?

Comment: @AlonzoArcher: This is basically just the same problem over again. An equation or relationship isn't "linear" *per se*; it's linear in a certain variable or expression. Thus, $z=3xy^2$ is linear in $x$ and in $y^2$ but quadratic in $y$. That article you link to isn't concerned with any of that; it focuses on the fact that "linear" is more general than "proportional" because there can be an additional constant term (against, constant with respect to some variable, function, ...). Thus $y=3x^2+z^3$ is linear in $x^2$ (with constant term $z^3$), whereas in $y=3x^2$, $y$ is proportional to $x^2$.

Comment: @AlonzoArcher: This is what they mean when they say that every proportional relationship is also a linear relationship -- that if $y$ is proportional to some variable, function, ..., e.g. to $x^2$, then that's a special form of linear relationship, namely one without a constant term.

Comment: I have never come across a description like "A is linear in B but quadratic in C". I think I must have an oversimplified understanding of linear where the equation does not have variables with powers higher than 1 degree, nor are there variables used as denominators. So I am not sure what it means to discuss a linear relationship in y^2 with z= 3xy^2. I'll ask some friends whether they understand. @joriki But, I think I understand the statement that although all proportional relationships are linear, but not vice versa. Just need to reconcile with how there is anything linear about y = 3x^2

Comment: @AlonzoArcher: You can find some examples e.g. with [this Google search](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22is+linear+in%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=zbP-Vb_dMcPnywOx2JaYCw#q=%22linear+in+x^2%22), e. g. [this first hit](http://dankalman.net/AUhome/classes/classesS12/linalg/assign1/starsols1.1.html) (Nr. 104).

Comment: Thanks for the reference @joriki! I just took a quick look and could tell it has some interesting stuffed so I book marked it for review. I tell you, there is always something more to learn about...keeps things interest though :-)